# Pandas: Create Column Values Based on Condition and Previous Rows Values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I would like to create a column, in this given example 'amount', within a Pandas dataframe 'df' where the value of each row is based on its previous rows as well as the value from another column 'id'. Example, if 'id' already has the value 30 assigned to it in the 'amount' column, then 0 else 30.

The expected outcome shown below:

```
id  amount
a   30
b   30
a   0
a   0
c   30
a   0
c   0
b   0
b   0
a   0
a   0
```

I thought I could accomplish this through some combination of groupby and lambda, but sadly I've repeatedly hit a wall.

What I tried out was:

`df['amount'] = df.apply(lambda x: 30 if df.groupby('id')['amount'].cumsum()<30 else 0)`

This gives me the following error:

`ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().`

I apologize in advance if the solution is obvious, but unfortunately, I haven't been able to find anything so far that would solve this.

Thanks

Comment: `df['amount'] = np.where(df.groupby('id')['amount'].cumsum() < 30, 30, 0)`

Comment: Thanks, Quang. I tried your approach and it, unfortunately, populates the value '30' for every single row, regardless if it already exists for an 'id'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thankfully was able to answer my own question. For anyone who is interested, I was successful with the following approach:

`df['amount'] = df['amount'].where(df.groupby('id')['amount'].shift().cumsum() < 30, 30)`

Thanks to everyone who shared their ideas!

Answer (score 1):

You can use an alternative column as such:

```
import numpy as np    
df1["pastcol"]=[np.nan]+list(df1["amount"])[:-1]
```

Output:

```
   id  amount  pastcol
0   a      30      NaN
1   b      30     30.0
2   a       0     30.0
3   a       0      0.0
4   c      30      0.0
5   a       0     30.0
6   c       0      0.0
7   b       0      0.0
8   b       0      0.0
9   a       0      0.0
10  a       0      0.0
```

Comment: Thanks, Francisco! I'm trying to avoid using a separate column for this. The idea would be to create the 'amount' column from scratch without any values at first. Hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

```
# Import Moduel
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Data Preparation and Preprocess
df = pd.DataFrame({'id':['a','b','a','a','c','a','c','b','b','a','a'],
'amount':[30,30,0,0,30,0,0,0,0,0,0]}
)
df['Orig_Index'] = df.reset_index().index
df['Dup_Seq'] = df.groupby(['id']).cumcount()+1
df_required = df.loc[df['Dup_Seq']==1].replace()
df_final = pd.merge(df, df_required[['Orig_Index','Dup_Seq']], left_on='Orig_Index', right_on='Orig_Index', how='left')
df_final['amount_v2'] = np.where(df_final['Dup_Seq_y'] ==1 , 30,0)
df_final.drop(['amount','Orig_Index','Dup_Seq_x','Dup_Seq_y'],axis=1,inplace=True)
df_final.rename(columns = {'amount_v2':'amount'},inplace=True)

# Data Display
df_final
```

Hi Francis,

Please try the code above and it will help you,

If you have any question please let me know

Thanks
Leon

Comment: I appreciate it, Leon! I was able to solve my problem with the following line of code: 

``df['amount'] = df['amount'].where(df.groupby('id')['amount'].shift().cumsum() < 30, 30)``